# Is "object.EnumConstant" instead of "Class::EnumConstant" a code smell?

Tags: c++, coding-style, enumeration

I have code like this

```
void disconnect(control::lib::DisconnectReason reason) {
   if(reason.getCode() == reason.C_Abnormal) {
     ...
   }
}
```

Is this a code-smell? I have never seen people doing that, but instead enum constants are accessed by the class name, usually. But this leads to long names, in my case

```
if(reason.getCode() == control::lib::DisconnectReason::C_Abnormal) {
```

What's the better thing to do here?

Comment: as far as I've seen people simply `typedef` them

Comment: @deW1 You can't `typedef` enumeration names.

Comment: I exclusively use the latter, but I can see what you're getting at as far as the names getting quite long with namespaces, etc

Comment: @JoachimPileborg my bad :>

Comment: But you can #define them :/ And that, for sure, smells.

Comment: why not add `using Reason = control::lib::DisconnectReason;` somewhere above `void disconnect(…)`?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem. Just like you can access class static variable with `.` or `->`, you can access enumeration names the same way, it just shouldn't be used becuase `.` (or `->`) suggests that this variable/name is caller-object's member, which is not true in these cases.

Comment: I bet OP knows that. Was more interested in possible drawbacks.